# Android Curved Button Layout

Tags: android, layout, canvas, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to make the following curved button layout in android, I just want to know if it is feasible with Android Layouts. If yes can anyone please help me how to work for these layouts.

Screenshot Attached

Here Circle is a Button C, Left hand side complete part is Button A, and the Right Hand side Complete Part is Button B.

I want to use the click events on all the three and the layout should look same as the image is attached

Here I just seriously want to say that, I have 3 images with me.. whole left purple part is button A (not only the rectangular one), and whole right purple parth is button B (not only the rectangular one). and the circle is in between both the buttons as shown in the layout. Now please help me.I have to make same layout. and I have left and right purple image and circle image too

Please help

[image]

Comment: try below solution and let me know what happens. @gaurav

Answer (score 1):

Use this, Create this XML inside your drawable folder and name it as `mybutton.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
    <solid android:color="#ABABAB"/> 
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

and then just add this to your button like,

```
android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
```

you can change color of button's and other parameter as per your requirement.

**EDIT**

You have to use RelativeLayout to achieve this as Circle is above ButtonA and ButtonB

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button     
android:id="@+id/btn_circle" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="100dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"     
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
/>              

<Button /* Button A, Align to parent left and bottom */ />
<Button /* Button B, Align to parent Right and bottom */ />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Here I just seriously want to say that, I have 3 images with me.. whole left purple part is button A (not only the rectangular one), and  whole right purple parth is button B (not only the rectangular one). and the circle is in between both the buttons as shown in the layout. Now please help me.
You have given the answer by thinking that I have to make just the rounded buttons. NOOO..I have to make same layout. and I have left and right purple image and circle image too

Comment: @GauravArora, then for setting that 2 button's just take 2 simple button's and set it's color to purple in background. That's it you don't have to do more for that. for setting color use `android:background="#Colorcode"` just get the color code and apply it here.

Comment: You are not able to understand my problem yet. Leave it

Comment: You are not able to understand about my requirement. Leave it. I want to make the same layout as above. The Complete Curved Button is a button which I have to make and I have to add a Circular button in between these two buttons as shown in the image attached in it.